# Chromium Embedded Framework binaries with h.264 support

Tags: h.264, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Does anybody know where to download CEF3 windows x64 bit binaries with h.264 support?

I want to use it in my project with CefSharp.
I know there is guide how to build it yourself, but it is too much GBs to download.

Thank you